# All my columns are indexes in pandas. How to solve that and 'reset' the index?

Tags: python, pandas

So, When i do `print(mydf.columns)` with my one of my dataframes, i get this result:

```
Index([
   'facility', '2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-04-01', 'YTD', 'state_name'
   ],
   dtype='object'
)
```

And because of that I can't join this dataframe with another one because i simply cannot specify which column i want to use as join parameter. To get that dataframe, i used this command:

`mydf = mydf[(mydf['facility'] != "Insert New ") & (mydf['facility'] != "Total")]`

How can i fix this?

Comment: unfortunately, this is not reproducible -- please specify the actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run `set_index` to set an index:

```
[ins] In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
   foo  bar
0    1    3
1    2    4
2    3    5

[ins] In [15]: df.set_index("foo")
Out[15]: 
     bar
foo     
1      3
2      4
3      5
```